# Why aren't my drop down lists working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

Doing portfolio page challenge on FCC. Can only use HTML/CSS/Bootstrap/jQuery.

**Problem**: Working on navigation bar and drop down, clickable, highlighted buttons. Copied the instructions from W3Schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar) is not working.

```
/*--Drop down buttons--*/
li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}

li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #000000;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
/*how does right:0; keep text from going off screen?*/
right: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #4CAF50}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
<!----Nav Bar ---->
<ul>
<li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown" style="float:right"><a href="#About" 
class="dropbtn">About</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">Life in Japan</a>
</div>
</li>
<li><a href="#Resume">Resume</a></li>
<li><a href="#Projects">Projects</a></li>
</ul>
<!---End Nav Bar---->
</div>
```

This is [my project](https://codepen.io/bomaran/pen/EvoRpR?editors=1100#0). Where is my code incorrect?

**Goal** = Create dropdown list for the "About" button. This list will highlight (as the other nav buttons do) when hovered over.

**Note:** CodePen allows me to import Bootstrap and use CSS in a separate box thats why no style tags are there. CSS is up top, HTML follows

Thank you

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in your question, formatted using the `{}` button on the toolbar. External links have a habit of going dead and it’s easier to read a question that only contains the parts that matter instead of all the parts needed for a demo. (Keep the demo link too, ’course!)

Comment: Have you linked your bootstrap js or jQuery file correctly

Comment: your css  have some issue also `< class="container-fluid">`  need to be `<div class="container-fluid">`

Comment: is this what you want https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzQvyL?editors=1100#0

Comment: @Ryan Hey Ryan, I tried initially and I just tried now but I do not understand how to link all of my code using that button. I press it and it gives me " `enter code here` " but when I copy and paste my code (it's long) it its not showing up properly. (I also wasn't sure what indent 4 times meant) I am extremely new to coding and StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `position:fixed` from `ul` or if you want to `position:fixed` for menu then remove `overflow: hidden`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*----not fully sure what overflow does--->*/
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #111;

  /*----Fixes Nav Bar to top---*/
  /*position: fixed;*/
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Alert user to their current link*/
.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

/*--Drop down buttons--*/
li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}


li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  right:0;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: blue;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!----Nav Bar ---->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown" style="float:right"><a href="#About" class="dropbtn">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">Life in Japan</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Projects">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
<!---End Nav Bar---->
</div>
```

Comment: This worked. Dropdown list is working from the about button, however "About" button and the dropdown list is off right side of the screen. Do you know where this mistake is?

Comment: remove the `style="float:right"` from about li or if you want About menu right side of the navbar then add css for dropdown `.dropdown-content {right:0}`

Comment: When I remove "style="float:right" [this happens](http://imgur.com/a/EiH3B) and my "About" button is moved to the left with the other buttons in the list. How would I keep the "about" button to the right? (I want it to be opposite the other buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code with and You missed some basic syntax.

Check the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ae175cdL/)

Updated code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!----Nav Bar ---->
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<!---End Nav Bar---->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this in your ul style. and it will work. Right now you have made it overflow:hidden, which causes your drop-down items to remain hidden.

```
ul {overflow: visible;}
```

for the second part, you just need to remove the `style="float:right"` from about li

Comment: If I remove float:right, the "About" button goes to the left side of the nav bar with the other buttons. I wanted to keep the "About" button alone on the right side of nav bar.

Comment: I set .dropdown-content for that button to right = 0; and that worked. Removing overflow: hidden also worked. But just to note [this example code](http://imgur.com/b0FAy7E) still has overflow:hidden but the dropdown is working still on this example.